# Can Google Chrome be made to auto reload after network outage in kiosk scenario?

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

I have an unattended touch screen kiosk application which needs to be able to automatically reload the browser home page after a network outage has occurred. At the moment the browser will display an "Unable to connect to the internet" error and will wait for a manual reload to be carried out before proceeding. Can this be automated?

I've searched for plugins and have found some plugins which deal with auto-reload but they don't seem to work in this context. I am guessing that the plugin is only active when a page is loaded so in this case with an error condition, perhaps the plugin is not active.

One alternative might be to override the error page which is displayed by Chrome but I don't know if this is possible. I could then instantiate a Javascript timer to try a reload every n seconds for example. Is this possible?

I saw a suggestion to use frames to allow the outer frame (which is never refreshed) to keep trying the loading of an inner frame but I'm not keen to use frames unless there is no alternative. I also saw a suggestion to use AJAX calls to check if the network was working before attempting a page load but this seems overkill if there is a way to correct the error only when it has occurred rather than pre-empt an error for every page load.

Host system is Windows 7 by the way. I'm keen to keep the browser running if possible rather than kill and create a new browser process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to tackle chrome extension development, you could wrap your site in an `iframe`, and then periodically refresh the iframe from the parent frame. That way you don't need to worry about OS issues.

Comment: Yeah that's worth a try. I wasn't keen to use frame sets as they are deprecated in HTML5 but iframes aren't. I'll give this a try and if it works then I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that works a treat. I had to mess about with CSS a bit to fully hide the iframe but I've now got a simple top level page which only loads once and which refreshes my iframe every n seconds. I've got a function to reset this timeout which can be called from within the iframe itself so the timeout can be prevented if there is activity within the iframe code. If I disconnect the network then I get an error but it reloads once the network is reconnected - exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if the content were loaded from ajax from the start then the it could simply output a custom message on the page as it does a check via AJAX. Probably prevention over remedy is always recommended

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure you are correct but I'm not sure I fancy having to convert my site to using AJAX for everything. I'm pretty new to web development and although my skills are improving rapidly, I fear I would struggle to carry this out. There are some places where this would make sense though such as in my 5 minute idle timeout which reloads the home page when there is no user activity for 5 mins. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming linux, you could create an ifup script to simply relaunch the browser with something like

```
#!/bin/sh
killall google-chrome
DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome
```

On debian/ubuntu, edit /etc/network/interfaces to include a post-up line; Google ifupdown for other distros.

---

On windows, you'd do roughly the same with a PowerShell script.

---

If you really want the precise behaviour you describe (without restarting the whole browser), I suggest you develop a plugin/extension: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: It's Windows 7 we're using as the host and I'd prefer to avoid restarting the browser if possible to maintain as seamless an experience for the end user as possible. I might be forced to create a plugin but I wasn't sure if the plugin API provides this sort of low level control. I'm also up to my ears with the actual web development so I don't really have time to take on plugin development too. Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using Chrome, but in Firefox this is trivial by overriding the [netError.xhtml](https://github.com/Webconverger/iceweasel-webconverger/blob/master/content/netError.xhtml#L410) page to do a `setTimeout(location.reload, 10000);`.